# Access column name inside function used inside summarize_all dplyr structure

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm building a `dplyr` structure to run some custom functions over the columns of a dataframe in 1 block of code

currently my function looks this

```
 funx <- function(x) {

  logchoice <- if(max(x) < 400) {'T' } else { 'F' }
  logtest <- suppressWarnings(log10(x))
  remaining <- length(logtest[which(!is.na(logtest) & is.finite(logtest))])
  x <- if(remaining > 0.75*length(x)) {suppressWarnings(log10(x)) } else { x }
  x <- x[which(!is.na(x) & is.finite(x))]
  y <- diptest::dip.test(x)
  z <- tibble(pvalue = y$p.value, Transform = logchoice)

  return(z)
  }
```

and the `dplyr` structure looks like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
 sample_n(30) %>%
 select(colnames(mtcars)[2:5]) %>%
 summarise_all(list(~ list(funx(.)))) %>% 
 gather %>% 
 unnest %>% 
 arrange(pvalue) %>% 
 rename(Parameter = key)
```

which gives me:

```
  Parameter     pvalue Transform
1       cyl 0.00000000         T
2      drat 0.03026093         T
3        hp 0.04252001         T
4      disp 0.06050505         F
```

I would like to know how I can access the column name inside my function, mainly because I would like to change the name in the result table to look like the output of this: `paste(original_column_name, 'log10', sep = '')` if the function applies the log transformation, but leave the original name as is when it decides not to.

so the expected output is:

```
   Parameter     pvalue Transform
1  log10_cyl 0.00000000         T
2 log10_drat 0.03026093         T
3   log10_hp 0.04252001         T
4       disp 0.06050505         F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close. You can just add a `mutate()` to the end

```r
mtcars %>% 
  sample_n(30) %>%
  select(colnames(mtcars)[2:5]) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~ list(funx(.)))) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  arrange(pvalue) %>% 
  rename(Parameter = key) %>% 
  mutate(Parameter = ifelse(Transform == "T", paste0("log10_", Parameter), Parameter)) %>% 
  select(Parameter, pvalue)

#  Parameter     pvalue
#  log10_cyl 0.00000000
# log10_drat 0.01389723
#       disp 0.02771770
#   log10_hp 0.08493466
```

Comment: I think this will always change the name right? not only when the condition inside the function is met. P.s. I'm updating the question with improved code as I'm working on another issue at the same time

Comment: see edit of the question with better example of the expected output

Comment: I see. Can you tack this on the end?
`mutate(Parameter = ifelse(Transform == "T", paste0("log10_", Parameter), Parameter))`

Comment: ah yes, that will do the trick. If you update your answer I will approve it. 
I also added %>% (Parameter, pvalue) to drop the T/F column that we don't need anymore

Comment: Still wondering if you can access the column name inside the function so that you can use it to print or display messages while inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Answering in a separate post as the solution is a different. To get the column names in a `print()`, I would pass them in the function and use `purrr::map_dfr` to build a dataframe of the result. The small changes I made are to grab the column name, `col_name`, and specify the dataframe. I tried a few approaches to grab the column name using your original function but came out unsuccessful.

```r
logtest_pval <- function(col, df) {

  col_name <- col
  x <- df %>% pull(!!col)

  logchoice <- ifelse(max(x) < 400, TRUE, FALSE)
  logtest <- log10(x)
  remaining <- length(logtest[which(!is.na(logtest) & is.finite(logtest))])

  x <- if(remaining > 0.75*length(x)) {suppressWarnings(log10(x)) } else { x }
  x <- x[which(!is.na(x) & is.finite(x))]
  y <- diptest::dip.test(x)

  z <- 
    tibble(
      transform = logchoice,
      column = ifelse(logchoice, paste0("log10_", col_name), col_name),
      pvalue = y$p.value
    )

  print(paste0(z, collapse = " | "))
  return(z)
}
```

Then you can build your dataframe:

```r
purrr::map_dfr(
  .x = names(mtcars), # the columns to use
  .f = logtest_pval,  # the function to use
  df = mtcars         # additional arguments needed
)
```

Here's another example

```r
df <-
  mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric)

pvalues <-
  map_dfr(names(df), logtest_pval, df)
```